# Make a react element appear on the front of fullscreen-ed child react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react component, let's call him ReactContainer.
ReactContainer contains a few elements which one of them is MyReactBox and one of them is ReactInnerContainer (a code example is below).

My problem is that if a put an element inside ReactInnerContainer into fullscreen using the requestFullScreen API, then it overrides on MyReactBox, although MyReactBox has the CSS zIndex property to the maximum value possible.

```
export default class ReactContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyReactBox />
                <br />
                <ReactInnerContainer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class ReactInnerContainer extends React.Component {

    handleFullScreenClick() {
        this.refs.innerDiv.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="innerDiv">
                /* Some stuff here */
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I wish that although innerDiv is in fullscreen, MyReactBox will still be shown on the front of the screen. If I render MyReactBox inside innerDiv then it works, but I need MyReactBox to be rendered in ReactContainer.

Any ideas how to solve the problem?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: As an aside - [strings as `refs` are deprecated, and will be removed in a future version of React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs). You should try to get into the habit of using functions, as Shubham Khatri has done in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `webkitRequestFullscreen` on the parent component

```
export default class ReactContainer extends React.Component {

    handleFullScreen (){
         this.screen.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={(screen) => {this.screen = screen }}>
                <MyReactBox />
                <br />
                <ReactInnerContainer handleFullScreen={this.handleFullScreen.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class ReactInnerContainer extends React.Component {

    handleFullScreenClick() {
          this.props.handleFullScreen();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                /* Some stuff here */
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: But then the whole div in the upper ReactContainer will go fullscreen, am I correct? I need only a specific element inside innerDiv in reactInnerContainer to go fullscreen, going in front of all of the elements in ReactContainer except of MyReactBox.

Comment: In that case, wrap the MyReactBox and ReactContainer in a div and call fullscreen on them together

Comment: You mean ReactInnerContainer right?
And for example let's assume I have many ReactInnerContainer elements inside ReactContainer. Any of them can go fullscreen, and I want MyReactBox to be shown whenever any of them goes to full-screen. How do I implement it according to your idea? It seems like I will have to put a different MyReactBox together with each ReactInnerContainer, but I need only one MyReactBox

Comment: We have to wrap the elements to go full screen within one div, we can't have multiple elements going fullscreen. In such a case, the scenario you mention is one to ponder upon. I don't have any idea as of now. If I get one, I will share, In case you get any let me know too